# How to skip the first facebook credential prompt?

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I'm writing a hybrid app with Ionic and the workflow I imagine for a perfect facebook integration would be the following:

**Scenario of a user logged in facebook with a native app:**

1. Open my app
2. Touch login with facebook
3. Be prompted for facebook permissions and approve
4. Be directed to the desired screen of my hybrid app

**Scenario of a user logged in facebook with his mobile browser:**

1. Open my app
2. Touch login with facebook
3. Be prompted for facebook permissions and approve
4. Be directed to the desired screen of my hybrid app

**Scenario of a user not logged in facebook (both in the native app and mobile browser):**

1. Open my app
2. Touch login with facebook
3. Be prompted for facebook credentials
4. Be prompted for facebook permissions and approve
5. Be directed to the desired screen of my hybrid app

**Is it possible to achieve as the mechanisms used to save session of a native app and a web app (facebook website) are way different?**

**How can I know if the native app is installed and once I know how can I use its session to prompt the user for permissions (as the android native apps do)?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are working with iOS then it might be worth knowing that the latest behaviour of the Login Dialog will not go to the Native app at all, it will use the SafariViewController. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/08/17/SDK-for-iOS9/

Comment: Very nice information @Bangdel, even using a webview it probably uses an existing session on the device. That is what I want to achieve basically, but with Ionic